# What is the difference between JavaScript's object literals and object that appears to be named when console logged?

Tags: javascript, json

I have noticed there are times when I console.log an object, I get the object literal and sometimes its seems what is *console.logged* is prefixed with a name.

For example, If I console.log an object before sending it to the server I get:

```
{id: 18, date: "2017-09-13T21:59:59.999Z"...etc}
```

but when I console the same log returned as a promise from a server call, I get:

```
Resource {id: 18, date: "2017-09-13T21:59:59.999Z"...etc}
```

What causes this differences? and What are the differences between what seems to be two different representations of an object?

Comment: The latter is a class instance. You can check this with `myObject instanceof Resource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is an instance of a named class:

```
class Resource {
   constructor() {
      this.id = ...;
      this.date = ...;
   }
}
```

Or a named constructor:

```
function Resource() {
  this.id = ...;
  this.date = ...;
}
```

In both cases, the class or constructor in instantiated with the `new` keyword, but `class` is the newer ES6 syntax.

```
console.log(new Resource())
```

Your first example is simply a plain object with no constructor.

Answer (score 1):

They have a `constructor` property, that does not point to `Object`, but to `Ressource` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The console is giving you hints, it doesn't always log stuff as is.

For example:

```
var Cat = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var paws = new Cat('paws');
console.log(paws);
```

will act similar to `Resource` in your example. The console is hinting at the `constructor`.